# Pipeline each line of a file to a specific variable in a second command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, pipe

I want to execute the following instruction:

```
basex -bword=ENTRY consulta.xq
```

But for every line of a SampleText file (plain text mainly).

The SampleText contains the following lines:

```
hello
evening
courageous
...
happy
```

So more or less what I want to do is to execute a instruction in a one liner recipe similar to this:

```
cat SampleText | basex -bword=EACHLINE searchquery.xq
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  basex -bword="$line" searchquery.xq
done <SampleText
```

Comment: what does the IFS mean in the above script?

Comment: @SamGoldberg: It's Input Field Separators, you can read this link for more details: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03